# Find the length of the longest odd-length palindrome that is a substring of a given string - Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I am not sure how to change my code to only look for odd sized palindromes. For example,

- In: "divider"
- Out: 5
- In: "Anna"
- Out: 2 (It should be 1)

Although Anna is a palindrome, it has even length. The only odd-length palindromes that are a substring of this string are strings of length 1 (a or n).
Any help is appreciated.

```
    entered = input()

    count = []
    for j in range(len(entered)):
        for i in range(j, len(entered)):
            if entered[j:i+1] == entered[i:j-1:-1]:
                count.append(i+1-j)

    print(max(count))
```

Comment: You can modify Manacher's algorithm to do this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring

Answer (score 0):

```
entered = input()
count = []
for j in range(len(entered)):
  for i in range(j, len(entered)):
    if entered[j:i+1] == entered[i:j-1:-1]:
      if(i+1-j)%2!=0:
        count.append(i+1-j)
print(max(count))
```

Comment: Adding the if condition is only checking if the entered string is odd. I need to check if the palindrome is odd. Another example would be the word "banana". It is an even size string but the palindrome "anana" is odd.